# NextJS i18 trigger page reload on locale change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

How exactly do I trigger a page reload from the code after user selects the language?

I'm using Next JS 10.0 and the new i18 features so my two urls are

- localhost/en/dashboard
- localhost/sp/dashboard

On my react button click I tried

```
router.push(`/${lang}/Dashboard`)
```

This works however is there a way where I don't have to manually re-code the current page location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use the `lang` or locale as part of your url string. Try the following instead.

```
    router.push('/dashboard', '/dashboard', { locale: 'YOUR_NEW_LOCALE' })
```

In case you're wondering why there are two '/dashboard', its because the first one goes as a `to` the second is an `as`. [You can read about it more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#transition-between-locales)

Comment: thanks very much for this!! I just have one issue, how do I know which URL I'm on? this is going to be messy if I try to figure out with window.location as it will already have   /en/dashboard so then I have to manually parse it?   Basically the language could be changed on any page because it's part of my top navigation bar

Comment: `router.pathname` will give you the location you're in. Also, If you're trying to navigate from one page to another without any other functionality you should consider using the `Link` tag. You can read about in the link I have included in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I just reload the page after the change language, but first you need to wait till the locale is completely changes then reload the page:

```
const handleChangeLanguage = (lang) => {
    router.push(router.pathname, router.asPath, {locale: lang});

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
        router.reload()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`router.reload()`

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreload)

Comment: thanks! I just saw in the doc you can pass the locale that's great. would you re-fresh the full page though when changing the language? this would do a hard refresh, is the right approach?